# enumitem: levels with inline option

Tags: lists, enumerate, enumitem, inline

I have a class file in which I need to set up the `enumerate` and the inline version `enumerate*` (as provided by the `enumitem` package with option `inline`). As defined, the two environments share labels, settings, etc.

I want them to be able to share levels (i.e. an `enumerate*` environment nested inside an `enumerate` environment is recognised to be at level 2), but I need to be able to adjust the formatting on the `enumerate*` environment (among other adjustments, I want this to start on a new line).

The problem is that I can't change `enumerate*` (e.g. using `\setlist`) without also changing `enumerate`. I can get around that by using (e.g.) `\renewlist{enumerate*}{enumerate*}{3}`, but then the nesting gets lost.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}

\setlist[enumerate]{align=left,leftmargin=8mm,labelsep*=0pt}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{label=(\alph*), ref=(\alph*)}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{label=(\roman*), ref=(\roman*),leftmargin=9mm}

\begin{document}

Here's a non-nested inline enumerate list:
\begin{enumerate*}
  \item blah
  \item blah
  \item blah
\end{enumerate*}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item blah
  \item Here's a nested inline list:
  \begin{enumerate*}
    \item blah
    \item blah
    \item blah
  \end{enumerate*}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

In this MWE, the challenge is to modify the preamble in order for both inline lists to start on a new line, but for the nested one to use `\roman*` labelling, while the non-nested ones uses `\alph*`.

Bonus points if you can do it entirely within `enumitem`, as the users of the class file would like to have features such as `[resume]` available.

Comment: Do you mean something like `\newenvironment{inumerate}{\par\begin{enumerate*}}{\end{enumerate*}}` with the usage `\begin{enumerate}
  \item blah
  \item Here's a nested inline list:
  \begin{inumerate}
    \item blah
    \item blah
    \item blah
  \end{inumerate}
\end{enumerate}` ?

Comment: That would add a new blank line, yes, but there are a few other tweaks (which I didn't mention, sorry) that need to be made to the `enumerate*` environment. The following gives the formatting I want, but doesn't respect the levels: `\renewlist{enumerate*}{enumerate*}{3}` followed by `\setlist*[enumerate*]{before=\vspace{6pt}\newline,itemjoin=\hspace{50pt}}`

Comment: Well, I can't get your code to compile (`LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end.`)  But note that in my approach, you can , inside of `inumerate`, temporarily redefine the `enumerate*` environment with the optional argument.  That is, `\newenvironment{inumerate}{\begin{enumerate*}[before=\vspace{6pt}\newline,itemjoin=\hspace{50pt}]}{\end{enumerate*}}`

Comment: Strange. It compiles for me, both in TeXLive (on a Mac) and MiKTeX (on Windows)... I take your point that optional arguments can be passed through - a nice feature.

Comment: Sometimes copy/paste introduces non-visible junk that screw things up.  I just instead posted an answer that may possibly give an approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than try to exchange code via comments, I thought I would just post what I have.

Here, I introduce the `inumerate` environment that is an inline `enumerate*` variety that modifies certain parameters of the enumeration that the OP seemed interested in.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}

\setlist[enumerate]{align=left,leftmargin=8mm,labelsep*=0pt}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{label=(\alph*), ref=(\alph*)}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{label=(\roman*), ref=(\roman*),leftmargin=9mm}
\newenvironment{inumerate}{\begin{enumerate*}[before=\vspace{6pt}\newline,
  itemjoin=\hspace{50pt}]}{\end{enumerate*}}
\begin{document}

Here's a non-nested inline enumerate list:
\begin{inumerate}
  \item blah
  \item blah
  \item blah
\end{inumerate}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item blah
  \item Here's a nested inline list:
  \begin{inumerate}
    \item blah
    \item blah
    \item blah
  \end{inumerate}
  \item Next outer item
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The above does not support `resume` because `inumerate`, being an environment, is grouped, and the data necessary to `resume` are lost.  Here I instead provide a pseudo-environment `xnumerate` that will support `resume`.

I also provide the original `inumerate` environment, modified to take additional optional arguments (except `resume`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}

\setlist[enumerate]{align=left,leftmargin=8mm,labelsep*=0pt}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{label=(\alph*), ref=(\alph*)}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{label=(\roman*), ref=(\roman*),leftmargin=9mm}
\newenvironment{inumerate}[1][]{\begin{enumerate*}[before=\vspace{6pt}\newline,
  itemjoin=\hspace{50pt},#1]}{\end{enumerate*}}
  \newcommand\xnumerate[1][]{\xnumerateaux{#1}}
\def\xnumerateaux#1#2\endxnumerate{\begin{enumerate*}[before=\vspace{6pt}\newline,
  itemjoin=\hspace{50pt},#1]#2\end{enumerate*}}
\begin{document}

Here's a non-nested inline enumerate list:
\begin{inumerate}
  \item blah
  \item blah
  \item blah
\end{inumerate}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item blah
  \item Here's a nested inline list:
  \xnumerate
    \item blah
    \item blah
    \item blah
  \endxnumerate
  \item Next outer item
  \xnumerate[resume]
    \item blah
    \item blah
    \item blah
  \endxnumerate
  \item Next outer item
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I like this. I can add `[1][]` into the environment definition to pass `enumitem` parameters through to `enumerate*`. There's just one issue (possibly not something that's ever needed to be done, but all suggestions welcome): `[resume]` doesn't work, presumably because `enumitem` doesn't understand what its resuming...

Comment: @RobertBrignall I am thinking that is because `inumerate` creates its own group and so the data necessary to perform the `resume` is lost upon exit from `inumerate`.

Comment: @RobertBrignall See my addendum.